# If function has a given limit then to prove that function is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

How to Prove that if a function $f : A \to \Bbb R$ has a limit $l \in \Bbb R$ at $c \in L(A)$, then it is bounded in a neighborhood of $c$,

i.e. there exists $M \in \Bbb R$ and $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta) \cap A$, $|f(x)| \leq M$.

Answer (score 3):

By definition of limit given $\epsilon =1$ there exist $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-l|<1$ for all $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$. Now for $x\in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$ we have
\begin{equation}
|f(x)| \leq |f(x)-l|+|l|<|l|+1.
\end{equation}
So, take $M=1+|l|$

Comment: What am I suppose to do after $M = 1 + |l|$ ?

Comment: This is an $M$ and you have got a $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for any $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap A$.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$\exists\;\delta>0\;\;s.t.\;\; |x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<1\iff$$

$$\iff L-1<f(x)<L+1\;\;,\;\;\;\forall\;x\;\;s.t.\;\;|x-c|<\delta$$